# Inheriting protected fields in template derived class of template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, protected

I'm having issues with accessing protected members in template subclasses of a template class.

Thing is, if I remove the templates, everything works fine. I know how to work around my problem in an ugly way, by simply writing "using Base::my_protected_member" for every single derived class. But why should I need to do that in the first place ?

Here's a minimal commented example

```
template<class T>
class Base
{
    protected:
        T x;
    public:
        Base(T x) : x(x) {}
};

template<class T>
class Derived : public Base<T>
{
    //using Base<T>::x; //why ?!

    public:
        Derived(T x);
        void print();
};

template<class T>
Derived<T>::Derived(T x) : Base<T>(x) 
{ cout << x << endl; } //works fine

template<class T>
void Derived<T>::print() { cout << x << endl; } //doesn't work

int main()
{
    Derived<int> d(4);
    d.print();
}
```

I don't quite understand what's going on, or how to work around this in a nice way. probably I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: Note that in the constructor you actually use the paramter `x`, not the inherited member.

Comment: yeah, my bad. But why I can't elsewhere since it's protected ?

Comment: No, even it it were public in the base, you'd have the same issue. See the related answers.

Comment: yeah, couldn't find related topics while searching, but the post is clearly duplicate. Basically : you hav to explicitely specify this->mymember in order to make the name dependent.